# finding element of specific field in pandas adjacency matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas adjacency dataframe where I need to be able to identify any element on that dataframe by its physical numbered position, not index or column position, nor its coordinate.

the data frame is a 10,000 x 10,000 adjacency matrix:

```
adj.shape

(10103, 10103)
```

Instead of doing something like

```
adj.iloc[coord1], [coord2]]
```

(which works fine), i need to be able to find the value on the data frame by its physical number from 0 - 100,000,000 (0 being the very first field and 100,000,000 being the very last.

I have tried (what i believe is) a clunky way of doing which is to stack the dataframe, convert to list then find the appropriate value at the index i am interested in:

```
adj().stack().tolist()[0]
```

(or any other number which tells me what the value is at that position. this also works perfectly, but I would like to be able to keep the adjacency matrix intact. any help would be much appreciated!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use integer division and modulo:

```
np.random.seed(1)

adj = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,20))
# print (adj)

N = 99
a = adj.stack().tolist()[N]
print (a)
0.6171449136207239

b = adj.iloc[N // adj.shape[0], N % adj.shape[1]]
print (b)
0.6171449136207239
```